# "be made of gold"

Tags: present-perfect, auxiliary-verbs, past-participles

1. Our houses have made of gold  [Present Perfect tense]
2. Our houses were made of gold  [Past Simple tense]
3. Our houses are  made of gold

I don’t understand why some people prefer to use **are + past participle** (3.)  rather than present perfect or past simple.

So when and why do we use are + past participle?

Comment: I fixed the subject (noun) and verb agreement.

Comment: A house made of gold? What was wrong with "a  house made of wood/cement/concrete/bricks"?